# Ways to make a sever-client connection between desktop-phone?

Tags: python-3.x, flutter, dart

**Idea**

I am tring to make two applications one on PC and one on android phones(maybe IOS). My desktop app is build on python and the phone app with .dart on flutter emul.

Basically the only thing I want is to pass a variable from my phone to a desktop and do something with it. Of course the 2 devices will be on the same home network.

**Question**

I have already tested HTTP requests and TCP connection and I got both of them to work. My problem is that I want this app to go online eventually and as things are the connection is made on my IPv4, that is different in every device.

How can I make the desktop server side to wait for a phone to connect on it and the phone to search and find the open IP and port and the name of the device?

Comment: This is a very broad and open-ended question with many possible answers (none of which are objectively the "right" answer) that isn't really suitable for StackOverflow. I'd suggest looking into one of the following: server hosting, cloud-based server hosting, or P2P networking.

Comment: @Abion47 The only thing going from app to app is an integer variable so i dont really need a server i will look into P2P networking thanks for the suggestions.